# Description is truncated when searching Youtube API

Tags: ios, youtube-data-api

Why Youtube API search returns truncated description for video?
Here is URL I am using to search videos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&part=snippet&safesearch=strict&restriction=US&key=%@&q=%@&pageToken=%@
```

How can I get full description for videos after search?

Answer (score 8):

The descriptions are truncated to 150-160 characters when calling the search service. As you can see when you make a search in [youtube.com](http://youtube.com), in the result list, comments are truncated, but when you go to the video page you can see the full description. It's the same principle with the api. You need to get the video id, and use it to call the [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=es) service, to get the information regarding the specific video.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, if the answer is wrong, please comment and I'll edit or delete it.